# Execute code after async function completed

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a following code (a part of function):

```
async addMarkers() {
    const timeout = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

    function geoRequest(order) {
    }

    function setMarker(order) {
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
      if(orders[i].google_coords === '') {
        await timeout(1000);
        geoRequest(orders[i]);
      } else {
        setMarker(orders[i]);
      }
    }
  }
```

I need to execute some code only after `for` loop is completed. What should I do? Wrap `addMarkers` into Promise or something else? I tried to execute callback as parameter of `addMarkers` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

`async` functions return promises.

```
addMarkers().then(() => doSomething());
```